# Business Logic Layer - Getting the Current User

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I have a business logic layer and 2 applications which use this, a MVC UI and a Web API project.

One of the properties on my classes is CreatedBy and UpdatedBy, which should hold the userid.

```
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedTS { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedTS { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
```

Given there are multiple consumers of the BLL what is the best way to capture the userId?

A) - Set this within the BLL using `Environment.UserName`?

B) - Ask the client to set it and use model data annotation to make this Required

C) - Ask the client to pass this into any Create or Update methods in the BLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FormsAuthentication in both MVC and WebApi, you can access properties `User.Identity.Name`.

```
int userId = db.Users.Single(r=>r.Name == User.Identity.Name);
```

In WebApi it will be `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

This approach is quite secure. If you store `userId` on client-side, user will be able to modify it.

Comment: The authentication mode is none `<authentication mode="None"/>`. We have an external service that runs on top of IIS that provides our authentication service. I just need help with the design of where to set the userid. BLL or client?

Comment: How are you determining current user if he is not authorized?

Comment: We have an external service that runs on top of IIS that provides our authentication service. I just need help with the design of where to set the userid. BLL or client?

Comment: BLL should keep `userId` and `authToken` dictionary. Each client should receive `authToken` and pass it to every request.

Comment: And the BLL should read the userID property and set this internally, so that the client is unaware?

Comment: Your authentication service should determine `userId` and pass it further to BLL.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`.

To do so, you must ensure that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is set to a principal representing the current user.  This is done in the UI tier, and will happen automagically if you:

- Use a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) in an ASP.NET application.
- Use a `RoleProvider` in a WCF application [by setting principalPermissionMode ="UseAspNetRoles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702542(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);` in a client application.

Comment: So set this in the UI/Client before accessing the BLL?

Comment: @JackRussell, yes, set it to a principal representing the authenticated user in the UI tier.